# Interpolation with the most recent value

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Say I have a set of `(x,y)` points in two arrays, `x` and `y` of the same length.

I would like to interpolate the values of `y` for new values  of `x_new`. However, this interpolation should use the **last** (as **"previously seen"**) value of `y` in the array.

In other words, the interpolation of

```
x = [0, 10, 15]
y = [1,  3,  6]
```

on

```
x_new = [1, 2, 9, 14, 16]
```

should return:

```
y_new = [1, 1, 1, 3, 6]
```

How can I do that in numpy? Is looping and manually checking the previous value my only alternative?

### Explanation

The first element of `y_new` is `1`, this is because its associated `x_new` value is `1`, and the greatest, smaller than `1`, `x` value is `0`, and its `y` is `1`.

Perhaps the best way to look at this is to consider `x` as temporal values, and I hoping to fill in `y_new` with the most recent `y` value.

Comment: I really don't follow how you arrive at `y_new` in your example. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Where do the values `10` and `16` in `y_new` come from? Neither is in `y`.

Comment: I suspect it should be `y_new = [1, 1, 1, 3, 6]`.

Comment: So sorry @NPE. My wrong. I fixed it.

Comment: If `x_new` is 9, `y_new` should still be 1, shouldn't it?

Comment: Correct. @WarrenWeckesser. It is fixed now. I need to be more careful when editing, sorry for that.

Comment: When people are asking for better ways to do something, I find it helps to give an example of the slow-but-working code (here, "looping and manually checking the previous value") which gives the desired values. That way there's no (well, less) ambiguity about what you really want, and it's easier to ensure that the output matches what you expect.

Comment: +1 Thanks @DSM - I fully agree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume `x` is in increasing order.  Here's how you could use `np.searchsorted` to do your interpolation:

```
In [194]: x
Out[194]: array([ 0, 10, 15])

In [195]: y
Out[195]: array([1, 3, 6])

In [196]: x_new
Out[196]: array([ 1,  2,  9, 14, 15, 16])

In [197]: i = np.searchsorted(x, x_new, side='right') - 1

In [198]: y_new = y[i]

In [199]: y_new
Out[199]: array([1, 1, 1, 3, 6, 6])
```

(`x_new` does not have to be sorted.)

This will give an incorrect result if any value in `x_new` is less then `x[0]`, but that shouldn't be problem, because the process isn't defined in that case.